# How filter catchall email account based on recipient address

Tags: postfix, spamassassin, spam-filter

// Background info

I am building a chrome plugin that forwards private messages from websites to your email and allows your email replies to be returned through the various sites private message systems. Basically, unify private messages and their replies through your normal email.

I am a web developer but have never done much with email, chrome extensions, or server management. It is mostly a learning experience.

// Environment

- Small Kimsufi dedicated server
- Generic ISPConfig 3 install using postfix and spamassassin running on Debian.
- Catch all account on system@domain.com

// The problem

How can I set up a filter that blocks all incoming mail that doesn't follow a set recipient naming scheme? I assume it would be a regex somewhere but I have no idea where or how it could be written to target recipient addresses.

// Allowed recipient addresses

- someoneOnXX@domain.com
- someoneelseOnXX@domain.com
- potatoOnXXOnXX@domain.com

// Not allowed recipient addresses

- someone@domain.com
- someoneelse@domain.com
- potato@domain.com

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
check_recipient_access regexp:/etc/postfix/access,
```

to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

In `/etc/postfix/access`, do something like:

```
!/.*OnXX<at> example\.com/  DISCARD
```